# What is the sequence type if ROC is an annulus in the z-plane

Tags: z-transform

if:

$|z|>|\alpha|$ is causal and right-sided

and:

$|z|<|\alpha|$ is anti-causal and left-sided

then, what is the annulus/donut-ring ROC?

$|\beta| < |z| < |\alpha|$

non-casual?  finite-length?  double-sided?

Answer (score 2):

if the ROC of a Z-transform is a ring on the z-plane, then the associated time domain signal is :

- two sided infinite length (hence non-causal)

and

- stable if the ring includes unit-circle or unstable otherwise.

Comment: What does "infinite length" mean here? If you're 2-sided or bounded between 2 finite poles then how are you of "infinite length"?

Comment: @JohnD it means a two-sided sequence $x[n]$ extends from $-\infty < n < \infty$, if its ROC is a circular region.